# Trying to find X,Y coords of a Table using offsetTop, offsetLeft, recieving NaN for both

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

My goal is to retrieve the X,Y coords of a table. I have looked around and found some answers but am having trouble with my code.

```
<script>
var obj;
var x;
var y;
function getXY(){
obj = document.getElementById('TableContent');
x += obj.offsetTop;
y += obj.offsetLeft;
alert(obj);
alert(y);
alert(x);
}
getXY();
</script>
```

When the alert for x,y are displayed,NaN. I am wondering if I have missed something. Very new to StackOverflow as well as javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: initially x has no value so x+= would get an error, as answered by Diego, it should be initialized first to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator "+=" is the same as `x = x + something`. And the first time x (and y) values are undefined (which is NaN).

```
<script>
var obj;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
function getXY(){
obj = document.getElementById('TableContent');
x += obj.offsetTop;
y += obj.offsetLeft;
alert(obj);
alert(y);
alert(x);
}
getXY();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that. Very Appreciated! Works great!